# Spring mvc-dispatcher issue

Tags: java, spring, servlets, websphere

Hello in my logfile SystemOut from WebSphere i see exception:

```
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper service SRVE068E: uncaught exception created mvc-dispatcher... java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.getStatus()I
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: show your `web.xml` code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very similar to [this issue](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-12151) in Spring.

Which versions of Spring and WebSphere are you using ?

Comment: Spring 4.1.0.RELEASE, WAS 7.0

Comment: This is exactly the versions related to the issue. It's fixed in Spring 4.1.1. Upgrade Spring and it should be ok :)

Answer (score 0):

The method getStatus was introduced in Servlet API 3.0. You need at least WAS 8.0

Answer (score 0):

The HttpServletResponse.getStatus() is there since Servlet 3.0 which is not supported on WAS 7.0 which is Java EE 5 compliant.